# ERROR on accept: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c++, c, linux

EDIT: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is in comment lower and the code actually works, problem was in different area. Sorry for bad posting, I cannot delete it now.

I know, that there are some pages about this already, but I really tried everything and nothing works. Im having this error all the time and my code looks like this:

```
int server_socket, new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server;
bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server));

server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
if(server_socket < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server.sin_port = htons(port_number);

if(bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) error("ERROR on binding");

if(listen(server_socket, 5) < 0) error("Failed to listen for connections.");

while(1)
{
  struct sockaddr_in client;
  unsigned int client_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  bzero((char *) &client, client_len); 

  if((new_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len)) < 0) 
  {
    if(errno == EAGAIN) continue;
    else error("ERROR on accept");
  }

  if((pid = fork()) > 0)
  {  // this is parent process
      close(new_socket);
  }

  else if(pid == 0)
  {  // this is a child process that will handle an incoming request
    long_pid = (long) getpid();   // current child's PID
    close(server_socket);  
    server_socket = -1;       //closing parent socket
    printf("A new connection accepted from blablabla, port %d by process %ld\n", port_number, long_pid);

   // ---- doing some staff, running the program
EDIT: while((msg_size = read(new_socket, received_data, BUFFER_SIZE)) >0)
  //  ---- when Im done:
      printf("closing newsock\n");
      close(new_socket);  // close the new socket
      new_socket = -1;
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  else error("fork() failed");
}

// close the server 
printf("closing an original socket\n");
close(server_socket);  // close an original server socket 
return 0;
}
```

I didnt have this problem before, when I was using nonblocking sockets. So problem is probably connected to them.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] as it has even got an unbalanced `}` in the child code!

Comment: Copy/paste the code that you have tested, else you are wasting everybody's time:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I fill in the blanks to make this into a compilable example (please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define port_number 2222
void error(char const *Msg)
{
    perror(Msg);
    exit(1);
}
int main()
{
    pid_t pid; long long_pid;
    int server_socket, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    bzero((char *) &server, sizeof(server));

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if(server_socket < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(port_number);

    if(bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) error("ERROR on binding");

    if(listen(server_socket, 5) < 0) error("Failed to listen for connections.");

    while(1)
    {
      struct sockaddr_in client;
      unsigned int client_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
      bzero((char *) &client, client_len); 

      if((new_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len)) < 0) 
      {
        if(errno == EAGAIN) continue;
        else error("ERROR on accept");
      }

      if((pid = fork()) > 0)
      {  // this is parent process
          close(new_socket);
      }

      else if(pid == 0)
      {  // this is a child process that will handle an incoming request
        long_pid = (long) getpid();   // current child's PID
        close(server_socket);  
        server_socket = -1;       //closing parent socket
        printf("A new connection accepted from blablabla, port %d by process %ld\n", port_number, long_pid);

//      ---- doing some staff, running the program
//      ---- when Im done:
          printf("closing newsock\n");
          close(new_socket);  // close the new socket
          new_socket = -1;
          _exit(0);
      }
      else error("fork() failed");
    }

    // close the server 
    printf("closing an original socket\n");
    close(server_socket);  // close an original server socket 
    return 0;
}
```

it seems to work without any issues.

Obviously you're establishing the listening socket with error checks in the parent process and the parent process then isn't doing anything with the listening socket that closes it, so you shouldn't be getting that error from the parent process.

My guess is you're probably mistakenly continuing the loop in the child (in the part you're not showing).

Comment: Im using while((msg_size = read(new_socket, received_data, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) in a part "doing some staff". Can that be a problem?

Comment: @MartinRešovský You'll only get EBADF if you try to deal with an unopened filedescriptor, a negative fd number, or if do stuff to a filedescriptor that's incompatible with the type of the underlying file.

Comment: Well, I know this in theory, but still I cannot find the mistake in practice. Only other thing doing in the part Im not showing with socket si the loop I put in comment. Basically, everything is happening in that loop, but I cannot remove it. It wouldnt work than

Comment: Okey, I tried to rewrite now once again and it works. I still have no idea why now yes, and than not, but for now Im happy :D Thanks for help